# Using Multi-Dimensional Arrays for Matrix Multiplication Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to write a code that multiplies two given matrices together and displays the results. Here is the code I have down so far:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double firstMatrix[][] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
    double secondMatrix[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

    double[][] thirdMatrix = multiplyMatrix((firstMatrix), (secondMatrix));

    System.out.println("The product of the matrices is ");
    for (int i = 0; i < thirdMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < thirdMatrix[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(firstMatrix[i][j] + " ");
            if (i == 1 && j == 2) {
                System.out.print("  *  ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("    ");
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < thirdMatrix[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(secondMatrix[i][j] + " ");
            if (i == 1 && j == 2) {
                System.out.print(" = ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < thirdMatrix[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%.1f", thirdMatrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

```java
public static double[][] multiplyMatrix(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
    double c[][] = new double[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                c[i][j] += ((a[i][k]) * (b[k][j]));
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

But when I try to execute the program I receive an Array Index out of Bounds Error which shouldn't be the case since my for loops are making sure not to step out of bounds from the array. I don't understand where to change my code because it looks fine until I try to execute. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The exception stack trace tells you what the index is, and where the exception is thrown. Don't ignore it. And use your debugger.

Comment: hi @JBNizet I did what you said and was able to identify where it looks like the problem is. Namely at 'c[i][j] += ((a[i][k]) * (b[k][j]));' but am not sure where to go from here. Any advice?

Comment: You're getting the crash because you're trying to access a[2][2] which doesn't exist. And also b[2][1] which also doesn't exist.

Comment: hi @onnoweb thanks for the response. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 1st matrix's dimensions is `mxn` and the 2nd's `nxp` then the product's dimensions `mxp`. Right?  
So this 2nd level of the triple loop should iterate through the 2nd dimension of the product array:

```
for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++)
```

should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++)
```

`b[0].length` is the number of columns of the matrix b.
**Also** the 3d level of the triple loop should be:

```
for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++)
```

`b.length` is the number of rows of the matrix b which is equal to the number of columns of the matrix a.
**Edit**
In a generalized version you could change this:

```
double c[][] = new double[3][3];
```

to

```
double c[][] = new double[a.length][b[0].length];
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double firstMatrix[][] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
    double secondMatrix[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

    double[][] thirdMatrix = multiplyMatrix((firstMatrix), (secondMatrix));

    System.out.println("The product of the matrices is ");
    for (int i = 0; i < thirdMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < firstMatrix[0].length; j++) {// check this one
            System.out.print(firstMatrix[i][j] + " ");
            if (i == 1 && j == 2) {
                System.out.print("  *  ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("    ");
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < thirdMatrix.length; j++) {
            if (i <= 1) {// you need are condition to stop
                System.out.print(secondMatrix[i][j] + " ");
                if (i == 1 && j == 2) {
                    System.out.print(" = ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < thirdMatrix[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(thirdMatrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

```java
public static double[][] multiplyMatrix(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
    double c[][] = new double[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        // Change b.length to b[0].length;
        for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
            // Change a.length to a[0].length;
            for (int k = 0; k < a[0].length; k++) {
                c[i][j] += ((a[i][k]) * (b[k][j]));
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: I hope I can help with your problem .... Never give up.